# EmberJS Form - select field not POSTed

Tags: forms, ember.js

I'm learning Ember and I'm trying to build an Ember form with a dropdown. I want to POST the following information:

```
category: "http://localhost:8000/api/categories/3"
title: "Do this"
```

What Ember is actually posting is: this:

```
{"data":{"attributes":{"title":"Do this now"},"relationships":{"category":{"data":null}},"type":"tasks"}}
```

The value of the category isn't posted and I'm not sure what I'm missing. I was able to list all the tasks and filter them by category so I suppose the models are fine.

---

**/app/models/task.js**

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  title: DS.attr('string'),
  category: DS.belongsTo('category')
});
```

---

**/app/routes/tasks/new.js**

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model() {
    return Ember.RSVP.hash({
       'task': this.store.createRecord('task'),
       'categories': this.store.findAll('category')
    });
  },
  setupController(controller, model) {
    const categories = model.categories;

    controller.set('categories', categories);
    controller.set('task', model.task);
  },
  actions: {
    saveTask(newTask) {
      newTask.save().then(() => this.transitionTo('tasks'));
    },

    willTransition() {
      this.controller.get('model').rollbackAttributes();
    }
  }
});
```

---

**/app/templates/tasks/new.hbs**

```
...    
{{category-select
            task=task
            categories=categories
            default=task.category
            value=task.category
            }}
```

---

**/app/templates/components/category-select.hbs**

```
{{#each categories as |category|}}
  <option value="http://localhost:8000/api/categories/{{category.id}}" selected={{is-equal category.id default.id}}>
    {{category.name}}
  </option>
{{/each}}
```

Comment: In action save, are you sure you have `category` in `newTask`?

Comment: @EbrahimPasbani with `console.log(newTask.get('category'));` there, I get: `Class {isFulfilled: true, __ember1472539479265: "ember560", __ember_meta__: Meta}`

Comment: Where is the piece of code which actually `set`s the `category`  in the `task` when the user selects one of the options? Should be something like `let task = get(this, 'task'); let selectedCategory = get(this, 'selectedCategory'); set(task, 'category', selectedCategory); this.sendAction('saveTask', task);`